# What reputation is required for tag edits without approval?

Tags: support, reputation, editing, tag-wiki, privileges

I thought tag edits can be done with 5000 reputation. Am I mistaken? My [edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1041443) is still waiting for an approval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, 5,000 reputation gives you the privilege to [*approve* tag wiki edits](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits). Users like me won't see those edits in the Suggested Edits review queue.

What you're thinking of comes with 20,000 reputation; a [trusted user](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) is capable of

> - Editing tag wikis without needing approval